# Indexing error in list in gee [is not a function)

Tags: google-earth-engine, list, index

how do I access an element from a index. I have created a list with feature and I want to access them and I am using .get function. However after getting .get it is returning error that it is not a function. What else can you use to call the elements of the list but not get.

````
// Initialize batches as an ee.List
var batches = ee.List([]);

// Generate batches
for (var i = 1; i <= 75; i++) {
  var batch_filter = ee.Filter.eq("batchNumber", i);
  var batch_name = "batch" + i;
  // Add each batch to the list
  batches = batches.add(ARSplit.filter(batch_filter));
}

var batch1 = batches.get(0)
print(batch1, "batch1") \\ prints feature collection 
var batch1_riceGeometryfl = batch1.geometry(); \\ prints batch1.geometry is not a function```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by this way

```
var batchGeometries = ee.List([]);
for (var i = 1; i <= batchlength; i++) {
  var batch_name = "batch" + i;
  var batch_variable_name = batch_name + "_riceGeometry";
  var batch = ee.FeatureCollection(batches.get(i-1));
  var batch = batch.first()
  var batch = batch.geometry();
  batchGeometries = batchGeometries.add(batch);
}
```